# Why Do I Lose The Content Of My Variable?

Tags: c++, variables, vector, structure

I'm trying to create a program that reads in User Input for a Bank Client. The information is stored into a structure vector, but whenever I try to call a specific value, i.e. client[0].name, after reading in the user's menu choice, the value of client[0].name is cleared.

Here is how I read in the values from a file:

```
bool startUp::readFile() {
ifstream inStreamS, inStreamC, inStreamA;
string line, line2;

inStreamS.open("staff.txt");
inStreamC.open("client-info.txt");
inStreamA.open("account-info.txt");

if (inStreamS.fail() || inStreamC.fail() || inStreamA.fail()) {
    cout << "File Open Failure." << endl;
    return false;
}

while (inStreamS >> e.userID >> e.pass >> e.role) {
    employee.push_back(e);
}

inStreamS.close();

int x = 0;
int q = 0;

while (getline(inStreamC, line))  {
    switch (x) {
        case 0:
            c.name = line;
            x++;
            getline(inStreamA, line2);
            c.accNum = line2;
            q++;
            break;
        case 1:
            c.address = line;
            x++;
            getline(inStreamA, line2);
            c.accType = line2;
            q++;
            break;
        case 2:
            c.social = line;
            x++;
            getline(inStreamA, line2);
            c.accBal = line2;
            q = 0;
            break;
        case 3:
            c.employer = line;
            x++;
            break;
        case 4:
            c.income = line;
            x = 0;
            client.push_back(c);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Something Broke While Trying To Read The Client File." 
<< endl;
            break;
    }


    /*c.name = line;

    getline(inStreamC, line);
    c.address = line;

    getline(inStreamC, line);
    c.social = line;

    getline(inStreamC, line);
    c.employer = line;

    getline(inStreamC, line);
    c.income = line;

    while (getline(inStreamA, line2)) {
        c.accNum = line2;

        getline(inStreamA, line2);
        c.accType = line2;

        getline(inStreamA, line2);
        c.accBal = line2;

        client.push_back(c);
    }*/
}

inStreamC.close();
inStreamA.close();
return true;
}
```

Here is the .txt file, with each line being a different variable, 5 lines per client:

```
test1
test1 test1
123456789
test1 t
1234
test2
test2 test2
234567890
test2 t
5678
```

Here is my structure:

```
struct Clients {
string name, address, social, employer, income, accNum, accType, accBal;
};
```

And here is where I lose the value:

```
void CAM::runCAM() {
system("clear");
cout << "\t============================================================" << 
endl;
cout << "\t|  Teller Terminal System - Client And Account Management  |" << 
endl;
cout << "\t============================================================" << 
endl;
cout << "[1] Add A Client" << endl;
cout << "[2] Add An Account" << endl;
cout << "[3] Edit Client Information" << endl;
cout << "[4] Manage An Account" << endl;
cout << "[5] Save Client And Account Information" << endl;
cout << "[6] Exit" << endl;
cout << "Please Choose An Option: ";
cin >> uI;

checkInput(uI);
switch (check) {
    case '1':
        system("clear");
        cout << "A New Client Will Be Added, Please Provide The Following: " 
<< endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');

        cout << "\n" << client[0].name;
        addClient();
        break;
    case '2':
        system("clear");
        addAccount();
        break;
    case '3':
        system("clear");
        cout << "\n" << client[0].name;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');

        editClient();
        break;
```

In case 3, the value is no longer printed, but it will be everywhere before that instance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @NathanOliver the problem with that ericlippert link is that its not about how to use a debugger, its more about thinking about your code. We also need a beginners guide to each common debugger, gdb in particular.